# Deriving massless point particle action from Maxwell action?

Tags: field-theory, action

Starting with the Maxwell action for a $U(1)$ vector gauge boson with a general metric and (I'm assuming) using a plane wave ansatz for the vector, is it possible to derive the action for a massless point particle?

EDIT: More information on what I'm trying to do. The Maxwell action and the action for a massless point particle are written in very different language (field values integrated over spacetime vs. particle trajectory integrated over time). But if I want to follow, say, the front of an EM wave, I should be able to get the massless point particle action from Maxwell. Does anyone know if this can be done and if so where?

Comment: Have you tried reading the wikipedia article on the [Action Functional](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_(physics)) yet?
It will give you the answer. If there is a specific part that you cannot understand then ask about it specifically.

Comment: @Flint72 I'm not sure I see how this helps. The Maxwell action and the action for a massless point particle are written in very different language (field values integrated over spacetime vs. particle trajectory integrated over time). But if I want to follow, say, the front of an EM wave, I should be able to get the massless point particle action from Maxwell. I'm just not sure how to do it or if this is discussed anywhere. I don't see anything about that in that article - but maybe I'm missing it.

Comment: That would be really good information to add to the question.

Comment: @DavidZ I mean, I thought it was obvious. But sure, I'll edit it.

Comment: Even if it's obvious to you, we don't know that it's obvious to you. The point of editing that into the question is to clarify why the Wikipedia article Flint72 linked doesn't answer your question.